# How to launch Spark's ApplicationMaster on a particular node in YARN cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a YARN cluster with a master node running resource manager and 2 other nodes. I am able to submit a spark application from a client machine in "yarn-cluster" mode. Is there a way I can configure which node in the cluster launches the Spark application master?

I ask this because if application master launches in master node it works fine but if it starts in other nodes I get this:

*Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030*.

and the job is simply accepted and never runs

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a new enough version of YARN (2.6 or newer, according to [Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)), you can use [node labels in YARN](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/node-labels-in-yarn-49792443).

This Hortonworks guide walks through [applying node labels to your YARN NodeManagers](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/configuring_node_labels.html).

If you use Spark 1.6 or newer, then [this JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7173) added support for using the YARN node labels in Spark; you then simply pass `spark.yarn.am.nodeLabelExpression` to restrict AppMaster node placement, and if you ever need it, `spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression` for executor placement.