# How spark container allocation is done

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working with a spark cluster which has three types of nodes. The edge node which is the entry point to he cluster and is where I should ssh to the cluster, master nodes (2 nodes) and worker nodes. This looks to be a normal architecture for spark cluster, However I don't know where the driver container gets launched when I submit my application in the 'cluster' mode. Does this go to one of the master nodes or workers?

Comment: the driver gets launched in the random order among the worker nodes.

Comment: you mean it can be either master or worker?

Comment: yes. If you pass supervise flag HA is provided by spark cluster.

Comment: sorry I didn't get what you mean, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch Spark's ApplicationMaster on a particular node in YARN cluster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383150/how-to-launch-sparks-applicationmaster-on-a-particular-node-in-yarn-cluster)